# TypedParameterExpression with Raven DB Any query

Tags: linq, ravendb

When I attempt to run the following query against Raven DB, I get a "Expression type not supported: System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression" exception.

```
        var userIdsICareAbout = Session.Query<User>()
            .Where(u => u.Username == username
                        || u.Managers.Any(m => m == username))
            .Select(u => u.Username)
            .ToList();

        var kudos = Session.Query<Kudo>()
            .Where(k => userIdsICareAbout.Any(u => u == k.GivingUserId)
                        || userIdsICareAbout.Any(u => u == k.ReceivingUserId))
            .ToList();
```

Can I make a query like this work somehow?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: The second query is the one that fails, right? Also, what is the type if k.GivingUserId?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pull out the user id from the first query, not the user name?  Also, you could build a static index using `LoadDocument` which would allow you to make one query instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
    var userIdsICareAbout = Session.Query<User>()
        .Where(u => u.Username == username
                 || u.Managers.Any(m => m == username))
        .Select(u => u.Username)
        .ToList();

    var kudos = Session.Query<Kudo>()
        .Where(k => k.GivingUserId.In<string>(userIdsICareAbout)
                 || k.ReceivingUserId.In<string>(userIdsICareAbout)
        .ToList();
```

You need to add `using Raven.Client.Linq` for allowing the `In<string>`